# How to login successfully in Instaloader in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, instaloader

I am trying to scrape data from Instagram using the 'instaloader' python modules. When using this code:

```
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
L.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```

The code throws the following error:

> ConnectionException: Login error: Unexpected response, this might indicate a blocked IP.

I've tried looking through the documentation and GitHub issues, but can't seem to find a solution. Please advise how to login successfully, or any other modules that I can use to scrape data?

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by logging in to your browser and then running the script.

I'm not sure of the cause, but that's how I fixed it.

Please note some of Instaloaders functionalities are currently not working, presumably due to an update on Instagram.

Answer (score 1):

It might be looks like your ip is blocked by Instagram server.

Comment: Use another device to code this exciting program

Comment: You don't have to comment you own posts - you can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar that required log in and at the begining there was no problem at all, until after many repeated log ins it stopped working, because instagram sees you as a "bot". *Kal-Toh*'s asnwer from above seems to solve this problem, probably because when you log in you are asked to pass a more advanced test (e.g. "I am not a robot" checkbox or a verification code to your email) which eliminates instargam's suspicions.

But if the information you are trying to extract is completly public (e.g. the number of somebody's followers) you can try running your program without logging in at all in order to avoid all the "bot" probelms.